# ConfigResolver class is calling multiple times for a request in SprinBoot + Keycloak multi tenancy implementation

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am working on a spring boot application. I need to integrate Keycloak with it with support for multi tenancy
I am trying PathConfigResolver to resolve tenant details from path
But while I am sending a request and debugging I found like the execution with in config resolver class happens multiple times(like 5 to 7). Actually is it required to be executed this much times    or is it a issue.
I feel like this much time of execution will make my application slow. So I need to confirm actually its a issue or common way of execution?